# JQuery to execute on change of taxonomy field

Tags: 2013, jquery, managed-metadata, taxonomy

I am trying to find a way to auto populate some values whenever I detect a change in taxonomy selection (ClientPeoplePicker control), how can I achieve this using jquery?

This is what I currently have:

```
 $("[id*='taxDepartment']").change( function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

Answer (score 7):

When the value in Taxonomy picker control (`ScriptForWebTaggingUI`) is changed, the event `Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.ScriptForWebTaggingUI.onTextChanged` is triggered by default.

This *custom* event could be registered for Taxonomy picker control as demonstrated below:

```
function initTaggingControl() {
    RTE.CanvasEvents.registerListener(RTE.CanvasEvents.editableRegionChangedEvent, Function.createDelegate(null, onCustomTextChanged));
}

function onCustomTextChanged(sender, args) {
   if(args.editableRegion.innerText.length > 0){  //if value is specified?
       console.log(args.editableRegion.innerText);  //print term label
   }    
}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(initTaggingControl, 'ScriptForWebTaggingUI.js');
```

> In the specified example term label will be printed every time once
>   the term is selected.

You also might be interested to find more details about `ScriptForWebTaggingUI` control in [this post](http://blog.vgrem.com/2013/01/23/using-sharepoint-taxonomywebtaggingcontrol-control-access-and-manipulate-from-client-side/).

Comment: Hi Vadim, your answer is very helpful. Would you be able to further advise how to ensure that the code execution triggers only when the taxonomy term is resolved (underlined)? I do not want my code section to trigger for every keydown as I am planning to query from another list. By the way, I managed to restrict the control by restricting the condition (args.editableRegion.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.FieldName == 'Department').

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be override onblur function, this way the code not trigger every keydown. Still, the inserted value is not validated yet.

```
function initTaggingControl() {
   RTE.CanvasEvents.registerListener(RTE.CanvasEvents.editableRegionBlurEvent, Function.createDelegate(null, onCustomBlur));
}

function onCustomBlur(sender, args) {
   if (args.oldEditableRegion.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.FieldName == "FieldName") {
      if (args.oldEditableRegion.innerText.length > 0) {
         console.log(args.oldEditableRegion.innerText);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As textboxes don´t fire the onchange Event when the values are inserted by script but only by user manually this won´t work.

You will have to attach/overwrite some builtin-Taxonomy scripts to execute your code.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that none of the answers here were accepted, and thought that maybe the reason why is in OP's comment to Vadim Gremyachev's answer, which is that OP wants a way to detect when the term is *resolved*, not detect a "change" on every keypress.

I was looking for similar functionality, tried Vadim's (and group's) answers, and was dissatisfied with both.  After playing around some more, I discovered that when the term "resolves", SharePoint puts the text into a `span` with the class `valid-text` (presumably to draw the underline).

Based on that, this is what I have come up with to detect when a term changes and is resolved in the taxonomy field.

Keep in mind - this is for SP 2013 and a *single* select taxonomy field only.  I am not sure at all if this will work for multi-select fields or on any other version of SharePoint.

(Also, I'm using jQuery, but you could adapt this to vanilla JS by using some other DOM ready event.)

```
function handleTaxonomyFieldChange (mutations) {
    var added = false;
    var removed = false;
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        mutation.addedNodes.forEach(function(addedNode) {
            if (addedNode.className === 'valid-text') {
                added = true;
            }
        });
        mutation.removedNodes.forEach(function(removedNode) {
            if (removedNode.className === 'valid-text') {
                removed = true;
            }
        });
    });
    if (added) {
        console.log('valid text added');
        // call some other function to do what
        // you want to do when a term is resolved
    }

    if (removed) {
        console.log('valid text removed');
        // call some other function if you have to
        // do any clean up if no term is resolved
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var taxObserver = new MutationObserver(handleTaxonomyFieldChange);
    // obviously change the selector to suit your environment / field name
    taxObserver.observe($('div[id^="MyTaxField_"].ms-taxonomy-writeableregion')[0], { childList: true });
});
```