# jQuery - Detect value change on page and call routine

Tags: jquery, column, event-handlers, ajax, edit-form

On an EditForm.aspx page I have a routine to hide/unhide a field based on the change of another field. It works fine on pageload, but I want to fire the change on the page itself if the user makes a change. What is the correct syntax to create the event? Thanks for the help!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var statusField = SPUtility.GetSPField('Status');
    var showOrHideField = function() {
        var statusFieldValue = statusField.Controls.value.substr(0,statusField.Controls.value.search("\\|"));
        if(statusFieldValue === 'New') {
            SPUtility.HideSPField('Comment');
        }
        else {
            SPUtility.ShowSPField('Comment');
        }
    };
    showOrHideField();

// none of these options worked
    $('#Status').bind ("change", function(){ showOrHideField(); });
    $('#Status').trigger('change');
    $('#Status').change(function(){ })
    $('#Status'.Dropdown).on('change', showOrHideField);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is a managed metadata (taxonomy) field a change event will not be triggered due to the way the field is implemented. Therefore one way to solve the issue is to create a function to listen for changes. I found a listener function and added it to your code. It seems to have the desired result, every time the metadata field is updated the showOrHideField function is run.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var statusField = SPUtility.GetSPField('Status');
    var showOrHideField = function() {
    var statusFieldValue = statusField.Controls.value.substr(0,statusField.Controls.value.search("\\|"));
    if(statusFieldValue === 'New') {
        SPUtility.HideSPField('Comment');
    }
    else {
        SPUtility.ShowSPField('Comment');
    }
};
//run on startup
showOrHideField();

//listener function
function initTaggingControl() {
    RTE.CanvasEvents.registerListener(RTE.CanvasEvents.editableRegionChangedEvent, Function.createDelegate(null, onCustomTextChanged));
}

function onCustomTextChanged(sender, args) {
   if(args.editableRegion.innerText.length > 0){  //if value is specified?
       console.log(args.editableRegion.innerText);  //print term label
       showOrHideField();  //run your function
   }    
}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(initTaggingControl, 'ScriptForWebTaggingUI.js');
```

I found the listener function from a couple of sources: 
[JQuery to execute on change of taxonomy field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160833/jquery-to-execute-on-change-of-taxonomy-field) 
https://blog.vgrem.com/2013/01/23/using-sharepoint-taxonomywebtaggingcontrol-control-access-and-manipulate-from-client-side/

Comment: Note that ``Function.createDelegate`` is old Microsoft specific IE8 code, that SharePoint still allows for backward compatibility, it is not part of the ECMAscript standard. More: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164893/differing-ways-to-make-executequeryasync-calls-function-createdelegate/164898#164898

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as below

```
$(statusField.Dropdown).on('change', function() { 
    alert('Changed');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Amal, I tried your idea but the event did not fire. I also tried
$(statusField.Dropdown).change(function() { alert('Changed'); });

This is a managed metadata field so not sure if 'Dropdown' is supported.

Answer (score 0):

The Status HTML element most likely has no id value 'Status'

So

```
$('#Status')
```

will always return `undefined`

```
var statusField = SPUtility.GetSPField('Status');
```

probably does some magic in the SPUtility to get the element reference.

Since you allready have the reference (provided SPUtility returns a proper DOM element)

You can do

```
statusField.addEventListener('change', function(){ ...your code... });
```

no jQuery needed, just plain good old ES5 JavaScript
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Note: if `statusField.Controls.value` is a string (I never used SPUtility)

It is easier to get the first value (or the whole as an array) with:

```
(statusField.Controls.value).split['|'][0]
```

Comment: Hi Danny, 
I found (statusField.Controls.value).split('|',1) returned ["New Field"]. What I have returns, New Field.

Comment: Compare your code with my code... I did **not** use the second parameter of the [.split function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). My code converts to an array, then gets the [0] element from the array