# Inside my Create and Edit forms can i capture the event when a Managed Metadata field is changed using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, csom, client-side-rendering

I am working on a built-in create and edit forms inside my list. now the list contain a managed metadata field named "Customer Name". now i want to capture when this field is changed, to populate a dropdownlist values based on the selected term.

now i checked the markup, and it looks as follow:-

[image]

where seems there will be a hidden input field, and two Divs which control the managed metadata..
so i am not sure how i can capture when this managed metadata field is changed? i tried something as follow:-

```
$("input[id='CustomerName']").onchange(function() {

$("input[id^='CustomerName']").onchange(function() {
```

i also try using change() instead of onchange(). but did not solve the issue...

Comment: Did you check this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160833/jquery-to-execute-on-change-of-taxonomy-field ?

Comment: @kekub thanks for the link which seems very useful.. but i am not sure how i can register this custom event inside my edit and create forms? i can use script editors ??

Comment: @kekub second question will this custom event fires on all the managed metadata columns inside my form? as i can not find where i need to specify the field title or internal name??

Comment: args.editableRegion gives you the node in the dom tree that has been modified in the given example. From there you can go through the parentNodes to check the field.

Comment: @kekub can you advice more on this please?

Comment: Sorry, I only did this a few years ago when we were on 2010. You can try to ask in the original question. I was referring to this quote: "By the way, I managed to restrict the control by restricting the condition (args.editableRegion.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.FieldN‌​ame == 'Department')"

Comment: @kekub now seems the listner on the link will fire whenever any field changed not just the managed metadata.. so if i use your syntax `args.editableRegion.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.FieldN‌​‌​ame == 'Department'` will it solve this?

Comment: did you wrap that change method inside a `$(document).ready()` function? Maybe it can't find that dom object whenever it's called.

Comment: @Mike yes i did this i opened a new question https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216376/how-i-can-get-the-field-name-which-caused-the-oncustomtextchanged-to-fire can you check it please.. as now i changed my appraoch to use SPutility

Comment: @kekub now i tried using `args.editableRegion.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.FieldN‌‌​​‌​ame == 'my column name'` but it returned un-defined.. meanwhile i open another question regarding this, So can you check it please if u have the time https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216376/how-i-can-get-the-field-name-which-caused-the-oncustomtextchanged-to-fire as i am using the SPUtility in the new question based on ur above reply..